# Passing non-tensor parameters to a Keras model during training / using tensors for indexing

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a Keras model that incorporates data augmentation in the model itself. The input to the model are images of different  classes, and the model is supposed to generate an augmentation model for each class which should be used for the augmentation process. My code roughly looks like this:

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
...further imports...

def get_main_model(input_shape, n_classes):
    encoder_model = get_encoder_model()
    input = Input(input_shape, name="input")
    label_input = Input((1,), name="label_input")
    aug_models = [get_augmentation_model() for i in range(n_classes)]
    augmentation = aug_models[label_input](input)
    x = encoder_model(input)
    y = encoder_model(augmentation)
    model = Model(inputs=[input, label_input], outputs=[x, y])
    model.add_loss(custom_loss_function(x, y))
    return model
```

I would then like to pass batches of data through the model which consist of an array of images (passed to `input`) and a corresponding array of labels (passed to `label_input`). However, this doesn't work since whatever is input into label_input is converted to a tensor by Tensorflow and can't be used for indexing in the following. What I've tried is the following:

- `augmentation = aug_models[int(label_input)](input)` --> doesn't work
  because `label_input is a tensor`
- `augmentation = aug_models[tf.make_ndarray(label_input)](input)` --> casting doesn't work (I guess because label_input is a symbolic tensor)
- `tf.gather(aug_models, label_input)` --> doesn't work because the result of the operation is a Keras model instance that Tensorflow tries to cast into a tensor (which obviously fails)

Is there any kind of trick in Tensorflow that would enable me to pass a parameter to the model during training that is not converted to a tensor or a different way in which I could tell the model which augmentation model to select? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To apply a different augmentation to each element of the `input` tensor (e.g. conditioned on `label_input`), you will need to:

1. First, compute each possible augmentation for each element of the batch.
2. Second, select the desired augmentations according to the label.

Indexing is unfortunately impossible because both the `input` and `label_input` tensors are multi-dimensional (e.g. if you were to apply the *same* augmentation to each element of the batch, it would then be possible to use any conditional tensorflow statement such as [tf.case](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/case)).

---

Here is a minimal working example showing how you can achieve this:

```
input = tf.ones((3, 1))  # Shape=(bs, 1)
label_input = tf.constant([3, 2, 1])  # Shape=(bs, 1)
aug_models = [lambda x: x, lambda x: x * 2, lambda x: x * 3, lambda x: x * 4]
nb_classes = len(aug_models)

augmented_data = tf.stack([aug_model(input) for aug_model in aug_models])  # Shape=(nb_classes, bs, 1)
selector = tf.transpose(tf.one_hot(label_input, depth=nb_classes))  # Shape=(nb_classes, bs)
augmentation = tf.reduce_sum(selector[..., None] * augmented_data, axis=0)  # Shape=(bs, 1) 
print(augmentation)

# prints:
# tf.Tensor(
# [[4.]
#  [3.]
#  [2.]], shape=(3, 1), dtype=float32)
```

**NOTE:** You might need to wrap these operations into a Keras [Lambda layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda).